# How to use maven outside company's network?

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

My `~/.m2/settings.xml` looks like

```
<settings>

  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.inst.maven_inst_plugin</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>local central mirror</id>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
     <url>http://maven.corp.org.com:9999/repository/public</url>
   </mirror>
   <mirror>
     <id>local codehaus snapshot mirror</id>
     <mirrorOf>codehaus</mirrorOf>
     <url>http://maven.corp.org.com:9999/proximity/repository/codehaus</url>
   </mirror>
   <mirror>
     <id>local codehaus mirror</id>
     <mirrorOf>codehaus snapshots</mirrorOf>
     <url>http://maven.corp.org.com:9999/proximity/repository/codehaus.snapshot</url>
   </mirror>
   <mirror>
     <id>local jboss mirror</id>
     <mirrorOf>jboss</mirrorOf>
     <url>http://maven.corp.org.com:9999/proximity/repository/jboss</url>
   </mirror>
   <mirror>
     <id>local maven2-repository.dev.java.net mirror</id>
     <mirrorOf>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</mirrorOf>
     <url>http://maven.corp.org.com:9999/repository/maven2-repository.dev.java.net</url>
   </mirror>
   <mirror>
     <id>local apache.snapshot mirror</id>
     <mirrorOf>apache.snapshot</mirrorOf>
     <url>http://maven.corp.org.com:9999/proximity/repository/apache.snapshot</url>
   </mirror>
   <mirror>
     <id>local maven-repository.dev.java.net mirror</id>
     <mirrorOf>maven-repository.dev.java.net</mirrorOf>
     <url>http://maven.corp.org.com:9999/repository/maven-repository.dev.java.net</url>
   </mirror>
   <mirror>
           <id> inhouse snapshot mirror</id>
           <mirrorOf>inhouse.snapshot</mirrorOf>
           <url>http://maven.corp.org.com:9999/repository/inhouse.snapshot</url>
   </mirror>
 </mirrors>
 <profiles>
 </profiles>
 <usePluginRegistry>true</usePluginRegistry>
</settings>
```

This works fine as long as I am in company or using `vpn`.

I was trying an idea and realized that since I am out of company's network, maven could not download, it hangs on

```
Downloading: http://maven.corp.org.com:9999/repository/public/org/codehaus/cargo/cargo-maven2-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
```

I trying setting up repository in my project's `pom.xml` as

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net</id>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But that did not help

**Question**
How can I ask  maven to work outside of my company's network?

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with Maven at all, it seems like http://maven.corp.org.com just isn't publicly accessible. If the dependencies are available to the public you can use a different, public, repository URL but if they're owned by your company there's nothing you can do. Why do you want to do it without the VPN anyway?

Comment: Yes, all dependencies are available outside. so I tried setting `<repository>` but that still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

`http://maven.corp.org.com:9999` will be your company's internal Maven repository to store company artifacts and act as a proxy to approved public repositories (something like Nexus or Artifactory). Your company will run an internal proxy for a number of reasons

- Speed of downloads
- Protecting IP/internal security
- User management to control access to project artifacts
- Compliance
- Licensing

I'm guessing the proxy is not publicly available. You could go on a public network and replace your `settings.xml` with your own pointing directly to public repositories and download whatever is in them, but your employer would probably prefer you didn't.

If you need to access Maven repositories from outside the office, I expect you should be using VPN.